# Laravel Timestamp Being Updated Without Explicit Call To Do So

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions, laravel-5.4

So I'm running into an annoying problem with Laravel update and save. I have a model/table `Invoice` and `invoices`, that has a timestamp `sent_at`.

`Invoice.php`

```
class Invoice extends Model {
    protected $dates = [
        "sent_at",
    ];
}
```

I have the following function that updates the `Invoice`:

`InvoicesController.php`:

```
public function postPayInvoice(Request $request, $invoiceId){
    $user = $this->apiResponse->user;

    $invoiceItemIds = $request->input("invoice_item_ids");

    $invoice = Invoice::with(["invoiceItems" => function($subQuery) use($invoiceItemIds){
        return $subQuery->whereIn("invoice_items.id", $invoiceItemIds);
    }])->where("id", "=", $invoiceId)->first();

    \Log::info("Load: ".$invoice->sent_at);

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        foreach($invoice->invoiceItems AS $invoiceItem){
            $invoiceItem->status = "paid";
            $invoiceItem->paid_at = Carbon::now();
            $invoiceItem->save();
        }

        $totalInvoices = $invoice->invoiceItems()->count();
        $paidInvoiceItems = $invoice->invoiceItems()->where("status", "=", "paid")->count();

        if($totalInvoices == $paidInvoiceItems){
            $invoice->status = "paid";
            $invoice->paid_at = Carbon::now();
        } else {
            $invoice->status = "partially_paid";
        }

        \Log::info("Pre: ".$invoice->sent_at);

        $invoice->save();

        \Log::info("Post: ".$invoice->sent_at);

    } catch(\Exception $ex){
        DB::rollBack();
        return $this->apiResponse->returnFail([], "Unable to Pay Invoice: ".$ex->getMessage(), 200);
    }

    DB::{$request->input("rollback", null) ? "rollback" : "commit"}();

    \Log::info("Post Commit: ".$invoice->sent_at);

    return $this->apiResponse->returnSuccess($invoice, "Invoice paid!", 200);
}
```

What this does is pays the selected `InvoiceItems` (child model of `Invoice`), and, if all `InvoiceItems` are marked as `paid`, then updates `invoices.status` to `paid` (or `partially_paid`) and `invoices.paid_at` to `Carbon::now()` (or `null`).

This all works fine, but somehow, this code is also updating `sent_at` (hence the `\Log` statements). When the code loads the `Invoice`, after applying all save logic, right after saving and finally right after committing, the `sent_at` attribute is logged:

> [2019-05-08 12:43:24] local.INFO: Load: 2019-05-08 12:42:50
>   [2019-05-08 12:43:24] local.INFO: Pre: 2019-05-08 12:42:50
>   [2019-05-08 12:43:24] local.INFO: Post: 2019-05-08 12:42:50
>   [2019-05-08 12:43:24] local.INFO: Post Commit: 2019-05-08 12:42:50

As you can see, the `sent_at` timestamp is consistently `2019-05-08 12:42:50`. But as soon as I re-query the database, the timestamp is `2019-05-08 12:43:24`, which is the value of the `paid_at` and `updated_at` timestamps.

[image]

(`status`, `sent_at`, `paid_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)

Note this is called from an API, with a subsequent request to load a list of `Invoice` models, which has the following logic to determine so additional logic:

```
$cutoff = $this->sent_at->addDays(3)->endOfDay();
```

But I don't see how that could modify the `sent_at` column (no save/update is called following, and even if it did, `2019-05-08 12:43:24` does not equate to `addDays(3)->endOfDay();`

Has anyone seen this before? It's messing up some ordering logic in another view, so I need to fix it eventually...

Edit

If I disable `$invoice->save();`, it's `updated_at` timestamp is still updated, but I have no idea why. And, oddly enough, disabling `$invoiceTransaction->save();` and `$invoiceItem->save();` results in no change to `updated_at`... Does result in bad data, but this is still in development.

Secondary Edit

```
"CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`description` text,
`subtotal` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`grand_total` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`status` enum('pending','sent','partially_paid','paid') NOT NULL DEFAULT 
'pending',
`sent_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`paid_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
```

I believe there is an issue there:

> `sent_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Comment: Does your class have any observers?

Comment: Nope; just a standard `extends Model`, with a couple normal functions, accessors and relationships.

Comment: Can you show `show create table invoices`?

Comment: Here's your problem: `\`sent_at\` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @aynber Thanks for pointing that out. In the migration, I have it as `$table->timestamp("sent_at");`, vs `paid_at`, which is `$table->timestamp("paid_at")->nullable();`. Guess it just needs to be `nullable()`?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would happen from the migration, since it it doesn't seem to be in the Blueprint at all. Very curious. I suppose you could always set that to nullable in the migration, and then just fix it manually in the database. (edit) Apparently it's a known issue?? https://ma.ttias.be/laravel-mysql-auto-adding-update-current_timestamp-timestamp-fields/

Comment: @aynber Yeah, never seen this issue before, and I've added plenty of additional timestamps. I've set it as `nullable()` and re-ran the migrations, now showing as `'sent_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,`.

Comment: I hadn't seen it, either. It turns out, it's a MySQL 5.7 setting. `The first TIMESTAMP column in a table, if not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT or ON UPDATE attribute, is automatically declared with the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes.`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

Comment: @aynber Well there ya go. Lesson definitely learned. You're welcome to add all that as an answer if you'd like. Thanks for finding that, much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the MySQL 5.7 configuration, and not Laravel.

> The first TIMESTAMP column in a table, if not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT or ON UPDATE attribute, is automatically declared with the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes.

[src - Mysql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp)

The fix is to set the timestamp to nullable in the migration, and/or alter the table manually.

```
ALTER TABLE invoices CHANGE sent_at sent_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```