# Laravel 6 - Updating the model timestamps

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, mysql-5.7

After some actions inside of my Laravel 6 app, I'm trying to update my model object `$last` (class CurrentConditions). As you can see below, I'm trying to update `update_time` property to current timestamp. Except this property, I have another timestamp property inside the CurrentConditions model: `external_update_time` and I want this property to stay the same after updating and saving `$last` object. Problem is that `external_update_time` property is updated to current time after saving the model.

```
/** @var CurrentConditions $last */
$last = $this->getLastUpdatedCurrentConditions($cityID);
$last->update_time = Carbon::now("UTC");
$last->save();
```

Here is my model:

```
class CurrentConditions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'current_conditions';

    ...

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $dates = ['update_time', 'external_update_time'];

    ...
}
```

And here is my migration code:

```
Schema::create("current_conditions", function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements("current_conditions_id");
      ...
      $table->timestamp("external_update_time");
      $table->timestamp("update_time")->useCurrent();
});
```

So why is `external_update_time` updating as well? Thanks for any help.

Comment: how did you define these fields in your schema, migration?

Comment: @lagbox Good point. I updated the question.

Comment: and this is mysql isn't it?

Comment: @lagbox Yes, it is, MariaDB 10.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Timestamp Being Updated Without Explicit Call To Do So](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045660/laravel-timestamp-being-updated-without-explicit-call-to-do-so) I faced this same issue a while back, and it happens when you have a non-nullable timestamp in your migrations; the first instance of said column will have an unexpected default update value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that external_update_time is not set on Update to set CurrentTimeStamp

in the schema table design

Answer (score 0):

This is how MySQL 5.7 works - first timestamp will be updated with current timestamp. You should modify order of columns in your migration (assuming it's not deployed yet to live server) to achieve what you want:

```
$table->timestamp("update_time")->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp("external_update_time");
```