# Why does this field change automatically

Tags: laravel

Model

```
...
protected $dates = [
        'closed_at',
    ];
...
```

table info

```
...
$table->timestamp('closed_at');
...
```

Why the `closed_at` field is automatically updated when I modify the model ?

Comment: Write code for controller also

Comment: I just run the code in Tinker, Like this 
`$post = Post::find(1); $post->title = 'new title'; $post->save();`

Comment: That shouldn't happen . The $dates  atrribute only cast it to carbon instance doesn't update it

Comment: I ran into the same issue a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045660/laravel-timestamp-being-updated-without-explicit-call-to-do-so. I think you've figured it out, but MySQL does some odd stuff with date fields. I think if you use `$table->timestamps()` in your migration, to add `created_at` and `updated_at`, you won't run into this problem, so something to consider in the future. That or include `->nullable()` on the migration.

Answer (score 0):

It will not take automatically. You have to insert it.

```
$post= Post::find(1);
$post->title= 'new title';
$post->closed_at=now();
$post->save();
```

For more information [see documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)
Or
You can check stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045660/laravel-timestamp-being-updated-without-explicit-call-to-do-so) for similar question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$table->timestamp('field')` is automatically maintained by mysql.
Like this `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`